# How to show alert from prohibited radio button combination

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 input type in my form the first code is for choosing product and the next code is for choosing payment method

```html
//below code is item selection
<input type="radio" id="layanan_163" value="163" name="layanan" data-type="diamond" required>
<label for="layanan_163" class="list-group-item h-100">
<div class="col nama-layanan-form">Starlight</div>
<div class="col nominal-price">USD 9</div>
</label>
<input type="radio" id="layanan_163" value="163" name="layanan" data-type="diamond" required>
<label for="layanan_163" class="list-group-item h-100">
<div class="col nama-layanan-form">Starlight Plus</div>
<div class="col nominal-price">USD 15</div>
</label>

// below code is payment method selection
<input required type="radio" id="method_4" class="radio-pembayaran" name="metode" value="4">
<label for="method_4" class="list-group-item h-100">Paypal</label>
<input required type="radio" id="method_3" class="radio-pembayaran" name="metode" value="3">
<label for="method_3" class="list-group-item h-100">Bank Transfer</label>
```

and the-not-allowed-combination is : when user select an item with price under USD 10 is not allowed to choose paypal as payment method (radio button can't selected)

how to show an alert if the visitor choose the-not-allowed-combination ?? in javascript ?

and how to disable visitor to not to choose the-not-allowed-combination ?

Comment: You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: already add some code.. need help please

Answer (score 0):

First, your two radio inputs with name="layanan" have the same value, which will be a problem, so give them a different value.
Then, you could add a **data-price="9"** and **data-price="15"** to them, so you can easily get their price.

In JavaScript now, and using jQuery to make the code easier to understand and shorter, you could do this:

```
$("input[name='layanan']").on('change', function() {
    var item_price = $("input[name=layanan]:checked").attr('data-price');
    if(item_price >= 10)
    {
        $("#method_4").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#alert_minimum_price_for_paypal").slideUp();
    }
    else
    {
        
        $("#method_4").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#method_4").prop('checked', false);
        $("#alert_minimum_price_for_paypal").slideDown();
    }
});
```

Also, add this line to write the message somewhere so people know why they cannot select PayPal:

```
<div id="alert_minimum_price_for_paypal" style="display: none;">You cannot use PayPal for payments under $10.</div>
```

To explain this:

- If there's a change on any input with the name "laynan" (the name of your two radio inputs)
- We put the price of the selected radio button in a item_price variable
- If the price is equal or over $10: we remove the "disable" attribute on the paypal radio input + hide the message
- Else if the price is less than $10: we add a "disable" attribute on the paypal radio input + display a message + uncheck the paypal radio button if it was checked, to prevent any problems afterwards

Of course, this is just JavaScript and that's easy to modify, so don't forget to also verify the amount in your server-side code to make sure someone won't pay something less than $9 using PayPal, even though very few people would trick the code to do so...

Comment: great explanation.. brb going to add some editing.. Big Thanks!

Comment: just a little question.. if i have 5 payment method how to disable all method payment if the price under $10 except paypal method ?

Comment: @zzzz You're welcome! You could add a data-price-under-ten="true" for the payment methods that are allowed for amounts under $10 (and with the value "false" for the others) on each radio input, and then in the if(item_price >= 10) condition of the code I gave you, add:
$("input[data-price-under-ten=true]").prop('disabled', false);
and in the else of the condition, this:
$("input[data-price-under-ten=true]").prop('disabled', true);